# How to make a smooth rotation during a continuous swipe on Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, ontouchlistener, image-rotation

I have a circle as `ImageView` and I want to be able to smoothly rotate it when swiping with a finger. If I swipe slowly, I want the circle to rotate slowly until the swiping action stops. If I swipe faster, I want the image to rotate more.

I've implemented the code that I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19067893/4054411). This longer version allows to change swiping direction without lifting the finger, so that the circle would start rotating to the other direction.

This is my `OnTouchListener` class:

```
open class OnSwipeTouchListenerV2() : View.OnTouchListener {

    private val SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 0f
    private var initialX = 0f
    private var initialY = 0f
    private var previousX = 0f
    private var previousY = 0f
    private var currentX = 0f
    private var currentY = 0f
    private var diffX = 0f
    private var diffY = 0f
    private var swipeH = "0" // Horizontal swipe direction (LEFT or RIGHT)

    override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        when (event.action) {

            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {

                initialX = event.x
                initialY = event.x
                return true
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {

                currentX = event.x
                currentY = event.x
                
                // These where original diff calculations
                // The issue with this is that diffs get bigger when swiping further
                // It is an issue because I'm trying to use the diff as an angle to rotate by
                // diffX = currentX - initialX  // Original
                // diffY = currentY - initialY  // Original
                diffX = currentX - previousX    // My Implementation
                diffY = currentY - previousY    // My Implementation

                when (swipeH) {
                    "LEFT" -> {
                        if (currentX > previousX) {
                            swipeH = "RIGHT"
                            initialX = previousX
                            diffX = currentX - initialX
                        } else {
                            // Intentionally kept empty
                        }
                    }
                    "RIGHT" -> {
                        if (currentX < previousX) {
                            swipeH = "LEFT"
                            initialX = previousX
                            diffX = currentX - initialX
                        } else {
                            // Intentionally kept empty
                        }
                    }
                    else -> {
                        if (currentX < initialX) {
                            swipeH = "LEFT"
                        } else if (currentX > initialX) {
                            swipeH = "RIGHT"
                        } else {
                            // Intentionally kept empty
                        }
                    }
                }

                previousX = currentX
                previousY = currentY

                if (abs(diffX) > abs(diffY)) {
                    if (abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight(diffX)
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft(diffX)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom(diffY)
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop(diffY)
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                swipeH = "0"
                initialX = 0f
                initialY = 0f
                previousX = 0f
                previousY = 0f
                diffX = 0f
                diffY = 0f

                return true
            }
            else -> {
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    open fun onSwipeRight(diffX: Float) {}

    open fun onSwipeLeft(diffX: Float) {}

    open fun onSwipeTop(diffY: Float) {}

    open fun onSwipeBottom(diffY: Float) {}

}
```

This is my `MainActivity` file:

```
class MainActivityBackup : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val wheel = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView1) as ImageView

        window.decorView.setOnTouchListener(object: OnSwipeTouchListenerV2() {

            override fun onSwipeLeft(diffX: Float) {
                rotateImage(wheel, diffX)
            }

            override fun onSwipeRight(diffX: Float) {
                rotateImage(wheel, diffX)
            }
        })
    }

    fun rotateImage(imageView: ImageView, angle: Float) {
        imageView.animate().rotation(angle).start()
    }
}
```

It kind of works, but not really... On emulator, if I swipe just a bit, then it works fine, but if I do a continuous swipe slowly, then the circle moves very little during the swipe and makes a normal rotation once the swipe is finished. Same happens during a fast longer swipe: the circle does not move during the swipe but rotates (more than during the slow swipe because I'm using `diffX` as an angle of how much to rotate) once the swipe is finished.

I've tried a different function for the actual rotation found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71615594/4054411). I've tried different interpolators, that did not help.

Maybe I should not be using `diffX` for rotation? But from `Log` messages (to get the value of `diffX` during each `ACTION_MOVE`) I saw that during a continuous swipe the circle definitely does not rotate as much as it is supposed to.

My guess is that this happens because during a continuous swipe the are a lot of `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` actions and each of them makes a call to `onSwipeLeft` or `onSwipeRight` functions, but they do not finish for some reason because a new `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` action arrives, right?

So, any ideas how to smoothly rotate a circle?

## Solved

Figured it out myself... I guess it was because I was using animation and when there are many `ACTION_MOVE` events happening, then animation just cannot keep up. This is the change that I've made (not exactly this, but it's the main idea why it was not working properly):

```
fun rotateImage(imageView: ImageView, angle: Float) {
    // old code
    imageView.animate().rotation(angle).start()

    // new code
    imageView.rotation = angle
}
```